# using xmlstarlet to pul

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

Given:

```
<UOIS UOI_ID="9c168282a881848971a85eaa32e7f213f7791e88" CONTENT_TYPE="VIDEO" NAME="2016_129_17_1_PM_Moss.mov" VERSION="1">
```

How can I use xmlstarlet to pull the values for `UOI_ID` and `NAME` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should output `UOI_ID` and `NAME`, from every `UOIS` element, separated by comma :

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//UOIS" -v "concat(@UOI_ID, ', ' , @NAME)" -n your_xml.xml
```

Comment: how do I pull elements from attributes from a different tags and concat them? See revised question.

Comment: @Bleakley That requires different approach since the target attributes reside in different elements. Please post new question for that. I will rollback your post since it invalidate existing answers.

Comment: @Bleakley also, please post well-formed sample XML there (there were some unclosed tags)

Comment: new question posted - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43216296/using-xml-starlet-to-pull-values    @har07

Answer (score 0):

So you can try this approach.

`$ xmlstarlet sel -t -v "/UOIS[UOI_ID= 9c168282a881848971a85eaa32e7f213f7791e88]/UOI_ID/" yourfilename.xml`

Apply the same idea for the name value. If you need any further assistance please, let me know!

Comment: Thx, I did not notice that.